# Squaring each digit of a number individually in javascript

Tags: javascript

I wish to know what is wrong with my code, it always returns an array of each individual digit of the input number, but not the squared results that I would wish for.
Here is the code:

```js
function squareDigits(num) {
  if (num >= 10) {
    let digits = num.toString().split('');
    let realDigits = digits.map(Number);
    realDigits.forEach(number => {
      return number * number
    });
    return realDigits;
  } else {
    return num * num
  }
}
```

Comment: Just want to note that you can prettify your code, the way you wrote it is difficult to read.

Comment: `let squared = digits.map(Number).map(x => x * x)`

Comment: @Alnitak: `map(Number)` can be safely omitted.

Comment: @georg it can, but the OP used it, and in my experience the best way to avoid "WAT?!" moments is to explicitly coerce your variables to the expected time at the earliest opportunity.    I don't mind using explicit unary operators to perform that conversion, but I draw the line at using implicit coercion via a binary operator.

Comment: @GTS consider *not* using a special case for the `< 10` code - not only does it create repetition in the code, but it also forces the function to return just a single number for that case instead of an array.

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is that you are not saving back on the array the square of the numbers inside the `forEach()` method. One simple modification on your code will do it:

```js
function squareDigits(num)
{
    if (num >= 10)
    {
        let digits = num.toString().split('');
        let realDigits = digits.map(Number);
        realDigits.forEach((number, idx) => realDigits[idx] = number * number);          
        return realDigits;
    }
    else
    {
        return num * num;
    }
}

console.log(squareDigits(3));
console.log(squareDigits(33));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

However, you can approach the same using a unique `map()` ([coercion](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839) to numbers will take effect when using multiplication operator):

```js
function squareDigits(num)
{
    if (num >= 10)
    {
        let digits = num.toString().split('');
        return digits.map(n => n * n);
    }
    else
    {
        return num * num;
    }
}

console.log(squareDigits(3));
console.log(squareDigits(33));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: neat, never considered messing with the styling of the output before

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that returning from a forEach doesn't modify the original array. Try using .map with a new output variable like this:

```js
function squareDigits(num) {
  if (num >= 10) {
    let digits = num.toString().split('');
    let realDigits = digits.map(Number);
    let squaredDigits = realDigits.map(number => {
      return number * number
    });
    return squaredDigits;
  } else {
    return num * num
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
squareDigits = num => {
  if (num >= 10) {
    return num.toString().split('').map(n => {
      n = Number(n) || 0;
      return n * n;
    });
  } else {
    return num * num
  }
}

console.log(squareDigits(3));
console.log(squareDigits(12123));
```

Comment: `Math.pow()` for a simple integer squaring?!

Comment: @Alnitak I have updated my code to not use `Math.pow()`